# react-syntax-highlighter is not working with TailwindCSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, react-syntax-highlighter

I am displaying sanity block content using [@sanity/block-content-to-react](@sanity/block-content-to-react). The BlockContent component is wrapper by div with class of "prose".

```
 <div className="prose prose-zinc font-display prose-h1:font-normal prose-code:mx-1 prose-code:before:content-none prose-code:after:content-none dark:prose-invert ">
     <BlockContent
         // Pass in block content straight from Sanity.io
          blocks={singleBlog.body}
          serializers={serializers}
      />
 </div>
```

In my serializers, I am passing custom `<Code/>` component.

```
  const serializers = {
    types: {
      code: (props) => <Code props={props} />,
    },
  };
```

In my custom code component, I am using Syntax Highlighter to wrap by code content.

```
      <SyntaxHighlighter style={theme} language={props.node.language}>
        {props.node.code}
      </SyntaxHighlighter>
```

But, no matter which theme I choose, it only changes the background colors and font sizes but has no effect in text colors.

[image: Sample code]

I thought 'prose' class on wrapper div was causing the problem. But remove that didn't work either.

```
          {/* <div className="prose prose-zinc font-display prose-h1:font-normal prose-code:mx-1 prose-code:before:content-none prose-code:after:content-none   dark:prose-invert "> */}
          <BlockContent
            // Pass in block content straight from Sanity.io
            blocks={singleBlog.body}
            serializers={serializers}
          />
          {/* </div> */}
```

Does anyone have any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are using a custom theme or if you are using one of the many option. But if you are using the available one that you can find here: https://react-syntax-highlighter.github.io/react-syntax-highlighter/demo/prism.html

Then it may be a problem with your imports.

If I import the theme like that (using the hljs ): `import {dark} from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs";` I only get background color.

If I import the theme like this using the 'prism' option I get the text color too: `import {dark} from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";`

Comment: Initially i was importing (using 'prism'): `import {dark} from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism"` ;

I tried the other way (using the hljs)  `import {dark} from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs` and it worked. I still don't know why but thanks for the idea.